# How To Run And Test a Windows Services In VS

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-services

I created a windows service in VS:File->New Project->C#->Windows Services
But I don't know how to run and test it.VS says I have to install my windows services to run it.but I Just want to test it and I don't want to install it.Can anybody Help me???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To debug your Windows service, add the following in your `Main()`:

```
if (!Environment.UserInteractive) {
    // We are not in debug mode, startup as service

    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyServer() };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
} else {
    // We are in debug mode, startup as application

    MyServer service = new MyServer();
    service.StartService();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

And the following method in your class `MyServer`:

```
public void StartService() {
    this.OnStart(new string[0]);
}
```

Now hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug, as any winform or console application.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a Windows Service I usually put all functionality into a separate class library... for testing I create a "normal app" which makes use of the class library...

AFTER the functionality is tested and the bugs are gone I do build/install the Windows Service... there can be problems specific to Windows Service like permissions etc. - these need to be addressed accordingly (some logging is usually very helpful).

Debugging a Windows Service with VS is a bit different from debugging an application - for details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A windows service is not really a normal executable, it builds as **exe** but has to be installed and started with Services icon from Control Panel.

Once you got it installed and started you can use Visual Studio **Debug** menu, Attach to process and attach to the service to debug it, not the simplest and fastest way to debug because if you need to change anything you have to build it again and install it again, start and attach again.

Usually a nice approach is to anyway split and isolate the logic of the service in a class library (probably the service business logic) which can be used also from let's say a console application.

At this point you create a test console application which calls some methods and behaves kind of like the service from the `Main` method and you test and debug this one.

Once everything has been tested and verified and you are satisfied with the results you copy the code you have put in the `Main` method of the test console application in the Service class, probably in the `OnStart` method or similar, details depend on your specific design.

we do this also to debug and test WCF services which are hosted in a test console app during development and in a Windows Service in production.

Answer (score 0):

you should use visual studio command prompt with the following command:

installutil "the path of the exe"

and the go to Services (start-> run-> services.msc) you will find the service. click on start and you're done.

P.S: to debug your service in vs: tools-> attach to process and find your service in the list)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot debug service directly from VS. Need to **attach the debugger** to Windows Service.

To do it, in VS do following:

1. From the Debug menu, select Attach To Process…
2. Near the bottom of the window, select Show processes in all sessions.
3. Left-click the compiled EXE to be run as the Windows Service in the list. Press Attach.

Result: you can place breakpoints at places in your functions, and you'll be able to debug the service execution.